# Какой знак нужен перед "всё"?

Tags: пунктуация

*— Так?*

*— Они нас голодом заморят. А так да всё так.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, допустимы и другие знаки, но я бы поставил *запятую:*

> — Они нас голодом заморят. А так да, всё так.

Чем мотивирую? Если взять просто *"да, всё так",* сложно поставить что-то другое, кроме запятой. А когда добавляется *"а так",* на мой взгляд, мало что меняется.

[Здесь](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85/) подтверждение моей уверенности в том, что после утвердительных *да* и *нет* нужна *запятая:*

> Слова *да* и *нет,* выражающие утверждение и отрицание, в составе предложения отделяются или выделяются запятой : – ***Да, да,*** не к чему, прикажи подавать лошадей (Бун.); – ***Да-да,*** разумеется! – торопливо разрешил Сидорин (Шол.); – Я с этим согласен, ***да, да!*** (Н. Остр.); – Видно, вы на весь госпиталь белье гладите? – ***Нет,*** тут много моего (Б. Паст.); – ***Нет,*** не выдумывайте, а расскажите всё как было (Пауст.).

Answer (score 2):

Я бы заменила первое слово ***так*** (хотя окончательное решение зависит от смысла текста). Мне кажется, что вторая реплика сказана с иронией, тогда это нужно как-то отметить.

— Так?

— Они нас голодом заморят. **А в остальном да, всё так.**

Answer (score 1):

Последняя фраза очень невнятная и спотыкливая. К чему в короткой фразе сразу два "така"?

Comment: Может-то может, только зачем?

Comment: Но вы же не просто фразы говорите в прямой речи, вы же пишете типа литературное произведение, верно? Зачем же писать его плохо, если можно писать лучше?

Comment: Так это смотря чья прямая речь. Во всяком случае, слепо копировать устную речь не стоит. Иначе можно дойти и до "э-э... мэ-э.." и тому подобного – ведь так почти все говорят? А текст, что вы выкладываете, – он неконкретный?

Comment: Боитесь, украдут? ) Вряд ли.